# How to extend the html Twig escaper?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, twig

I'm progressively migrating an existing Symfony application to VueJS.

The issue I recently discovered is the `{{ stuff }}` markup are always interpreted by VueJS, even if the content come from a rendered twig variable.

To avoid this, I would like to extends the `html` escaper to replace `{` and `}` by the respective `&#123;` and `&#125;` html codes.

How can I do that properly? The escaping is inside a `twig_escape_filter` without a service I can override.

I also tried to make a custom escape strategy guesser, returning my `vue` escaping, itself calling the `twig_escape_filter` with `html` escaping before replacing the needed characters. All my source code was escaped. :-D

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

In fact you could solve this problem in your javascript as simple as that:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.options.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
```

Now you can use  double brackets (`{{ }}`) for twig like you did before and `${ }` for VueJs.

**EDIT**: What you want to do is impossible. You can indeed convert `{{ }}` to its corresponding html entities using a simple filter like this:

```
new \Twig_Filter('yourFilter', function ($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_HTML5);
}, ['is_safe' => ['html']])
```

but since Vue runs on top of your rendered html, the conflict you present will still occur (because html will render these html entities as brackets).

Your only solution is to use a more specific delimeter for your Vue like this one, to avoid this conflict:

```
Vue.options.delimiters = ['$vue{', '}'];
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not helping at all. This is not a Twig conflict issue, but about content show from database. Not all the application is migrated to vue and some database content may contains the delimiters.

So if a customer open a ticket with `${ something }` inside the text, I'll have the exact same issue.

Comment: This is why I need the html escaping of `{` and `}` from twig.

Comment: I edited my answer to better explain my proposed solution.

Comment: I'll not use a fancy delemiter for that, sorry. It's a workaround. :-)

And why my needs is impossible? The Twig_Extension_Core::setEscaper method exist, so I thinkg we can. I just don't really now how, this is why the asking. ;-)

Comment: I explained thoroughly why can't. Good luck with that!

Comment: Actually I even provided you a way to escape brackets with a simple filter function.

Comment: I know, thanks! But I would like to be the default escaping for html. Thanks for your time BTW.